# How to embed html elements within another html element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

What I've to do is something similar to "form.io" (a builder of forms), but the problem is that I don't know how to embed HTML elements inside another HTML element.

This is an example of a form.io functionality, that I created: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YhQLlYbs99udvCW-BgQRF06Ca_M9Hpww/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you expound on what you're wanting? What exactly are you trying to put inside of what - what would be a concrete example (e.g. what specifically in that video are you trying to replicate)? To put one element inside another you just do `<div> <button></button> </div>` - but I doubt that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Alexis Do you want to create a drag n drop functionality?

Comment: it is good practice to never add a link to external code in your question/answer. Can you edit your question adding what you have tried?

Comment: @VikrantBhat I want to drag and drop and embed an HTML element inside another HTML element.

Comment: @ScottyJamison No dude, that's not what I looking for. What I need is to drag and drop and embed an HTML element inside another HTML element. This is not what I need `<div> <button></button> </div>`

Comment: @Giuppox The link that I posted is not a code, it is just an example of a form.io  functionality that I want to implement.

Comment: ah, ok, you're looking for drag-and-drop. It takes a bit of work to implement that kind of thing (more than what people are usually willing to do in an answer), but there's a number of online tutorials you can follow and modify to work the way you need it. This MDN article gives you a higher-level idea, and you can use it as a reference as you try to build out your own: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: @AlexisPatiño check this out https://github.com/bhatvikrant/drag-n-drop-using-vanillajs

Comment: @VikrantBhat Ok, thanks bro, this can be of great help! :D